# Bad alloc when trying to initialize matrix C++

Tags: c++, matrix, bad-alloc

I am trying to put a 2d matrix into an AVL tree. However I keep getting a "terminate called after throwing an instance of bad_alloc." error and then the program crashes. Here is my code:

```
struct Node
{
  int key;
  struct Node *left;
  struct Node *right;
  int height;
  int **M;
};

struct Node* newNode(int key)
{
 struct Node* node = new struct Node;
 node->key   = key;
 node->left   = NULL;
 node->right  = NULL;
 node->height = 1;  

if(key == (0 % 3)){
    cout <<"Matrix" <<endl;
    int n = pow(2, 20);
    node->M = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        node->M[i] = new int[n];
    }     
//  freemat(node, n);
}
 else if (key == (1 % 3)){
    cout <<"Matrix" <<endl;
    int n = pow(2, 19) + pow(2, 18);
    node->M = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        node->M[i] = new int[n];
    }    
//  freemat(node, n);
}
else if(key == (2 % 3)){
    cout <<"Matrix" <<endl;
    int n = pow(2, 18) + pow(2, 17);
    node->M = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        node->M[i] = new int[n];
    }   
  //    freemat(node, n);
  }
  return(node);
}
```

The freemat is a function i created to free the matrix because i thought that was what the problem was, but i still had the problem even after "freeing" the matrix.

```
int freemat(struct Node *N, int n){
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    delete [] N->M[i];
  delete [] N->M;
}
```

The program compiles, prints out the word 'Matrix" and then prints the error underneath.

Comment: By my calculations, the shown code attempts to allocate at least four terabytes of memory. Are you sure your computer has that much RAM?

Comment: Unrelated: Avoid using `pow` to calculate exponents of 2. Not only is is brutally slow compared to left-shifting 1 (eg `1<<20`), `pow` deals in floating point and you could get truncation when you store the result in the `int`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik is that so? No i dont have that much Ram. Is that all the problem could be cause i resarched bad_alloc and sometimes the error is caused by something in the code and not because memory ran out. I just want to be sure

Comment: The only real difference in your branches is the value of `n`. The rest is identical. You may want to make that more clear -- i.e. don't put all the other stuff in branches and try to make your `n`-calculation branch free.

Comment: If you don't have that much RAM, then why are you writing code that tries to allocate that much?

Comment: the n is in branches because they depend on the value of key. I dont know how to not branch it out @Clearer

Comment: @SamVarshavchik its my homework. Its what we are asked to do

Comment: In `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        node->M[i] = new int[n];
    }` you allocate up to 1048576 `int`s 1048576 times. Think you want to re-read that homework assignment. You are missing something. Or your instructor is a right <expletive deleted>.

Comment: @user4581301 he asked us to put the matrix in the avl tree with those values but i wrote that code like that because i thought that was how were to initialize a 2d matrix. Is that not how to initialize a 2d matrix?

Comment: Again, you still don't quite comprehend that whatever the right or the wrong way to initialize a matrix is, if you need a matrix that's four terabytes big, you need a computer with at least that much RAM. Once you have sufficient memory in your computer, for your matrix, then you can work on figuring out how to initialize it.

Comment: That is a way to make a 2D matrix, but I question the size of the matrix required. Few instructors assign homework that a student cannot test and debug on a home computer. You are likely missing a trick somewhere.

Comment: Okay, i now agree that it must be because i ran out of memory cause i edited the code and instead of using those pow values, I used n = 2, 4, 6 and the code ran just fine.

Comment: @user4581301 i dont think so. just doing what i was asked. We are supposed to choose 100,000 values between 0 and 299(for the key part) for insertion and deletion into the avl tree making sure we do not have more than 50 nodes. And we are supposed to initialize our M's to those values depending on the key

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really know what can be done to help you here. The answer to the direct question is, "You ran out of RAM." How to fix unfortunately can't currently be specialized past "Use less RAM."

Answer (score 1):

The bad_alloc usually comes from you running out of memory. Have you tried running this under gdb to see this in action? 2^20 *2^20 * sizeof(int) is roughly 8 TB!

Also, some unsolicited comments (feel free to disregard): it looks like you are coming at this from a C background based on your freemat function and how you initialize your struct. Unlike C's malloc method, which returns NULL if it cannot allocate the requested memory, C++'s new function throws bad_alloc instead.

Finally, your check for (key == (1 % 3)) doesn't make sense. 1%3 is always one, so unless you intend to check for (key == 1), you might want (key % 3 == 1) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to the question -- sorry, but it's too long for a comment.

A way to get rid of all the branches

```
static const powers[] = 
{
    1 << 20,
    1 << 19 + 1 << 18
    1 << 18
};

std::cout << "Matrix\n";

int n = powers[key % sizeof(powers)];
node->M = new int*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    node->M[i] = new int[n];
```

This will still allocate a massive amount of memory and will still break your computer and make it catch flames.

Comment: thank you. somebody said something similar about using this leftshift operator but shouldnt it be 2 << instead of 1 <<?

Comment: It should be `1 << ` -- consider `pow(2, 0) == 1` and `1 << 0 == 1`, `pow(2, 1) == 2` and `1 << 1 == 2`.